# Prove that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to c} {f(x)} = \left| c \right|$

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove the following?

> If $f(x)=\left| x \right|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to c} {f(x)} = \left| c \right|$

I have thought of making use of the triangle inequality: $\left| {\left| x \right| - \left| c \right|} \right| \leqslant \left| {x - c} \right|$ but I'm not sure how to get the result from there?

Comment: Given $\epsilon\gt 0$, let $\delta = \epsilon$.

Comment: The inequality you have used is called reverse triangle inequality. You are  almost done.

Comment: Note that you can get away with just `\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = |c|`. No need for `\mathop`, no need for `\limits`, no need to wrap $f(x)$ in curly brackets, and since the letter $c$ isn't particularly tall, no need for `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *so close*. Set $\delta=\epsilon$, then take your inequality and stick $<\delta=\epsilon$ at the end:
$$
||x|-|c||\leq |x-c|<\delta=\epsilon
$$
and you're done!

Of course, in order to actually have a finished proof, you need to start with some standard stuff, like "Given any $\epsilon>0$". For instance, a proof could look like this:

> Given any $\epsilon>0$, set $\delta=\epsilon$. Now as long as $|x-c|<\delta$, we have, by the triangle inequality
>   $$
> ||x|-|c||\leq |x-c|<\delta=\epsilon
> $$
>   showing that $\lim_{x\to c}|x|=|c|$.